# Moq verify is not working as it looks like it should be

Tags: c#, moq

I have the following code in a test in my code. Note that this test was not written by me, the code it is calling was also not written by me, but I have changed it.

```
        mockedIMessage.Setup(m => m.ScriptMethodInvoker(EnumFunction.MsgFullSetPosition, It.IsAny<Result>())).Returns(1).Verifiable();
        var result = GetTestExecutionResult(script);
        mockedIMessage.Verify(m => m.ScriptMethodInvoker(EnumFunction.MsgFullSetPosition, It.IsAny<Result>()), Times.Once);
```

On the original code, this works. On mine, it doesn't - it tells me that the expected invocation on the mock was 0 times, not the once expected.

However, when I step it through in debug mode, it most definitely does call this code, and completes without throwing an exception. So the code appears to work, but the Moq is not detecting that it has been called.

Comment: Is the method you are calling virtual?

Comment: how did you change the original code? - please post your changes/code ...

Comment: The functions are not virtual, but they are now called as lambda functions. That is the main functional change. None of the other 2000 tests have a problem, but this may be different, by using the Verify.

Comment: we still need the code - what do you mean called as lambdas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what you provided, multiple mistakes could have been made:

- Make sure you are calling `ScriptMethodInvoker()` on the mocked `IMessage` instance
- If `ScriptMethodInvoker()` has overloads, make sure the right one is called
- Make sure `EnumFunction` is an enum
- If `EnumFunction` is not an enum then make sure that `EnumFunction.MsgFullSetPosition` always returns the same instance
- Make sure `GetTestExecutionResult()` actually calls `ScriptMethodInvoker()`.

Comment: This is a useful checklist - I had been through it largely, however when I came to the last one, that is where the issue seems to be. The IMessage is a mocked object at the point of calling, but when I call IMessage.ScriptMethodInvoker, it doesn't return the result specified in the mock above (1 in this case). So I am guessing that it is somehow calling the wrong version of this ( although how I am not yet sure).

Comment: To be honest, the code sample you posted doesn't make much sense in terms of unit testing: you set up a mock to return something on a specific call, but then you only verify that the same method is called on the mock. You should rather verify that the data the mock returns is used correctly later. Also `.Verifiable()` can be removed when you use `Verify(...)` with parameters specifying what should be verified.

Comment: You get the solution mark, because re-checking these items and i found it - a mistake on my part (I wasn't calling MsgFullSetPosition, but something very similar, and hadn't spotted the difference)